# Mantener sesión iniciada con firebase y kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Tengo un problema con mantener la sesión iniciada con firebase authentication y kotlin, cuando cierro mi aplicación y la vuelvo a abrir se muestra por una fracción de segundo mi actividad de registro e inicio de sesión y posteriormente se muestra mi actividad principal.

Esta es la clase de mi activity principal:

```kotlin
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Funcion para registrar nuevos usuarios e iniciar sesion con usuarios existentes
        setUp()

    }

    private fun setUp() {

        signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (editTextEmail.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.text.toString(),
                    editTextPassword.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        showHomeActivity()
                    } else {
                        showAlert()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (editTextEmail.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.text.toString(),
                    editTextPassword.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        showHomeActivity()
                    } else {
                        showAlert()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showHomeActivity() {

        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    private fun showAlert() {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Error")
        builder.setMessage("Se ha producido un error autenticando al usuario")
        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null)
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()


    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            showHomeActivity()
        }
    }

}
```

Me comentaron que revisara en mi manifest si esta actividad era la primera que se ejecuta al abrir la aplicación y lo revisé y si está bien, entonces no se cual sea el problema (AuthActivity es mi actividad donde hago login y registro de usuarios y HomeActivity el menú principal por así decirlo)

Comment: mmm... si tu launch en el manifest es HomeActivity, tal vez esa actividad, presenter... esté realizando alguna acción en el onStop, onPause para que al entrar se produzca ese blink... no sé si podrías compartir más info... siempre que el usuario abre la app va a la home? en qué casos se abre AuthActivity? Cómo se caduca la sesión?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tienes, El problema es mas que nada un error de concepto, lo que pasa esque cargas primero la pantalla del login y luego, de modo Asíncrono, checkea si existe actualmente un usuario, esa llamada, dependiendo de tu conexion puede tardar mas o menos. con el codigo como te muestro, el problema desaparecera pero te recomiendo que pongas un ProgressBar al inicio antes de checkear el usuario y quitarlo cuando tengas el resultado para que el usuario, en caso de conexion muy lenta no crea que la aplicacion esta congelada.

```
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    private fun setUp() {

        signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (editTextEmail.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.text.toString(),
                    editTextPassword.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        showHomeActivity()
                    } else {
                        showAlert()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (editTextEmail.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.text.toString(),
                    editTextPassword.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        showHomeActivity()
                    } else {
                        showAlert()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showHomeActivity() {

        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    private fun showAlert() {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Error")
        builder.setMessage("Se ha producido un error autenticando al usuario")
        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null)
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()


    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            showHomeActivity()
        } else {
            setUp()
        }
    }

}
```